# Improper Resource Access Authorization - Checkmarx -Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, checkmarx

I have a piece of code

```
@Repository
public interface AbcRepo extends MongoRepository<Abc,String>{
@Query(value = "{endDate:{$lt:?0}}")
public List<Abc> findAllInfo(DateTime t);
}
```

Whille running the  code through the checkmarx. I get a "Improper Resource Access Authorization" finding.

Any help on how to address the issue?